# How did the stormtroopers know which Jawas captured the droids?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, droids, stormtroopers

When Kenobi and Luke come upon the remains of several Jawas and their sand-crawler, Luke recognizes them as the same Jawas that sold C3PO and R2-D2 to his uncle, Owen. From there, Luke hops on his speeder and drives back to his family homestead to discover his aunt and uncle were killed.

There was that one scene where stormtroopers find the escape pod and determine that droids must have been aboard it. While that tells them what to look for, it is not enough to know where the droids are. They are somehow able to track the droids to Jawas and then determine that the Jawas had the correct droids, and that the droids sold the droids to a pair of moisture farmers.

**How did the stormtroopers know which Jawas captured the droids?**

And how did they know the Jawas visited the Lars homestead to sell a pair of droids?

Did they search the Jawas' computer memories for recent transactions of who bought droids?

Looking for canon-based answers.

Comment: Follow droid tracks to sandcrawler tracks.  Follow sandcrawler tracks to sandcrawler.  Search sandcrawler.  Droids not on board, backtrack and check everywhere sandcrawler stopped.

Comment: @DavidW I thought it was this trivial, too. But if you think about it, why don't they already search the locations where the sandcrawler stopped while they are following its tracks?

Comment: @Annatar We don't know exactly how many stormtroopers were involved in the search.  It's entirely possible that they *did* have a couple troopers break off at each stop while the main team kept following the crawler.  We don't know for sure that the crawler was destroyed before the moisture farm, just because Luke found them in that order.  The point is that they found the crawler (your actual question) by tracking the droids from the escape pod, and they found the farm by tracking the crawler.

Comment: @DavidW Following droid or sandcrawler tracks might not be that easy when they drive over solid rock.

Comment: @Annatar Obviously they don't necessarily have competent leadership in the Empire, but if an intelligent leader were running things they would focus on the _moving_ target first, before it expands the potential search area more than necessary.  It's always possible to backtrack to fixed settlements later, they're not going anywhere.  Plus the majority of droids would be on the crawler, unless you think the Lars looked rich enough to buy half a dozen droids.

Comment: @LincolnMan Well we know that 3PO got picked up on sand, having opted to stay on sand when R2 headed for rockier ground.  So we know that it would be possible to follow 3PO's tracks to the sandcrawler.  And the sandcrawler is big enough it can't pick an arbitrary direction through the rocky areas; the occasional trace of it in a patch of sand, broken bush or a rock crushed between the tracks would be enough to follow it.

Comment: This subject makes me think of _Monty Python and the Holy Grail_, where the police were trying to track down whoever killed the Famous Historian.

Comment: @DavidW If an intelligent leader were running things, they would have left some troopers at the Lars farm to ambush Luke just in case he comes back ;). No, honestly, I think this is just a piece of Fridge Logic that Lucas and his team never really thought through.

Answer (score 2):

The story of how the *Imperial Stormtroopers™* managed to track down down the droids is told in a [booklet](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_troop_transporter_(story_booklet)) that was packaged with the *[Imperial Troop Transporter](https://starwarsblog.starwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/original-transporter-1024x429.jpg)™* toy.

In short, the Stormtoopers identified tracks from both droids leading away from the pod in different directions. They used their transporter (a repulsorlift craft that leaves no tracks) to trace one set and the other set was followed by a *[Dewback](http://theswca.com/images-toys/figuretoys/dewback-front.jpg)™* unit. The set followed by the transporter led them directly to the *[Jawa Sandcrawler](http://theswca.com/images-toys/figuretoys/sandcrawler-front.jpg)™*.

I've reproduced the story in its entirety below.

> It seemed impossible! Two mindless
> droids had made off with design prints of the
> Empire’s most devastating weapon. ..Death
> Star™
>
> As the search squad left the Imperial
> Cruiser, a report came through from the on-
> board Scanning Stations. The droids’ Escape
> Pod had been tracked to an arid region on
> Tatooine known as the Central Lowlands.
> The exact ground position had been lost as
> the Pod went beyond the Scanner’s range,
> but, in all that sand, a metal Pod should not
> be hard to find, not with the Imperial Troop
> Transporter!™
>
> Landing at pre-set coordinates, the Troop
> Transporter of the Imperial Empire was there to
> meet them...long, sleek, deadly, with the Imperial Crest over the side hatches. The great, steel
> blue craft was operated by two drivers and could
> hold all six members of the search squad. Each
> Trooper entered a Traveling Rack on the side of
> the Transporter. They rode standing up in individual racks since their white and black armor
> made it almost impossible to sit. The rear of the
> vehicle contained a Prisoner Immobilization
> Unit for the detention and taming of renegade
> droids. And, for heavy resistance, there was
> always the Laser Blaster mounted on the upper
> deck. Even at night, the Transporter looked fearsome with the glare of its black, flip-up lights.
> One driver reported that Dewback™ ground
> units had spotted the Pod just a short distance to
> the north. Not bad for a Dewback outfit! But,
> the Transporter would take over the search from
> that point. It could cover twice the distance in
> half the time.
>
> The Transporter hovered a few feet above the
> surface and sped to the Pod landing site, but the
> droids and the plans had long since gone. **They
> left only two sets of tracks in the sand that were
> spared by the mid-day winds. The Dewback had
> already gone after one set of tracks. The Transporter locked onto the other set and headed east.
> The Surface Scanner in the Transporter soon
> picked up an old Class “D” transport slogging
> through the sand. Something the Jawas called
> a Sandcrawler™ Over the external sound system, they were ordered to halt in the name of the
> Empire. They kept moving. Two rounds were
> fired across the Sandcrawler bow from the 50
> megatome Blaster on the upper deck.** The Jawas
> stopped and came out to greet the Imperial
> boarding party.
> They had many droids in their inventory, but
> not the ones Darth Vader wanted back. Two
> droids were looted from the cargo bay and
> placed in the Droid Prisoner Compartment for
> further “questioning". **A sale had been recorded
> to one Owen Skywalker of two droids for his
> moisture farm. That’s all the Troop Commander
> had to hear.** The order was given to open fire and
> the Jawas were cut down in mid-step...
> defenseless.
>
> As the Transporter left to find the Skywalker
> farm, the heavy gun fired once at the
> Sandcrawler’s mid-section. It exploded and
> burst into flames.

Comment: You can see the full instruction booklet (complete with pictures) here; https://www.jeditemplearchives.com/vintage-star-wars/instructions/Vintage-Instructions-SW-Imperial-Troop-Transporter.pdf

Comment: Instruction manuals notwitstanding, your canon mileage may vary when it comes to this story. Owen isn't called Skywalker and we don't see the sandcrawler 'blown up' in the film (although we don't see it from every angle).